Prob laws used for prob of drawing a 7 before 8 when using two dices
A pair of dice is cast until either the sum of seven or eight appears.
Show that the probability of a seven before an eight is 6/11.
I initially looked at the problem like this:
P(7) is 6/36, and P(8) is 5/36
And I initially tried to reason myself to something like the probability of observing 7 before 8 to be equal to:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-P(A)-P(B))^{n-1} \cdot P(A)$$
However, after looking at it I discovered there are multiple things that are wrong here, the first is that the each throw is independed and as such the probability does not change regardless of how many throws of not observing 7 and eight that has occurred previous.
We know that P(7) is 6/36 and P(8) is 5/36, next I try to look at the conditional probability in this way:
$$P(A \mid B) \cdot P(B)=P(A \cap B)$$
Define P(A) as probability of observing 7, and P(B) as probability of not observing 7 or 8 on the dices.
So I look at it as follows:
$$\begin{aligned} & P(A \mid B)=P(7)+P(B) \cdot P(A \mid B) \\ & => P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(7)}{1-P(B)}\end{aligned}$$
However, if we look at this notation it is not correct, so how would you write this so that I can use the laws and that it makes mathematical sense.

You can ignore all outcomes and all rolls that do not result in a 7 or an 8.  You get then only one throw of the dice that matters.  The probability of it being a 7 is $\dfrac{6}{6+5}$

As for your attempts, they seem reasonable... but perhaps you would benefit from using subscripts to refer to which time it was you are throwing the dice so as to not have overloaded usage of labels for different events.  The infinite sum is fine, no worry about independence or changing values there.

Note: Any roll other than 7 or 8 has no effect and can be ignored.  To clarify the question is really asking, "What is $P(\ ($ sum $=7)|($ this is the last roll) )?"  So we consider the last roll.  The last roll must have a sum of either 7 or 8.
Let A = the sum of the two dice is a 7.
Let B = the sum of the two dice is a 8.
Again, the question is asking us to find
$$P(A\ |\ ( A\text{ or }B) )$$
Before getting into the formula, let's find $P(A \cup B)$.
$$P(A\text{ or }B ) = P(A) \cup P(B) - P(A\cap B)= \frac6{36} + \frac5{36}-0 = \frac{11}{36}$$
Then the question is asking for
$$P(A \ | \ ( A\text{ or }B) )= \frac{ P(A) }{P(A \cup B)}= \frac {\frac6{36}}{\frac{11}{36}} = \frac{6}{11}$$
Tadahh!

if anyone has the time, how do I adjust the fraction over fraction not looking right?  Feel free to post a link, suggest an edit, or in a comment, type mathjax syntax for it.
The $\frac{6/36}{11/36}$

@JMoravitz  The question says "A pair of dice is cast until either the sum of seven or eight appears." So there could be multiple tosses, 5 tosses, 10 tosses, theoretically even 100 tosses with no sum of 7 or 8.  But like JMoravitz, each toss is independent because they are dice.  Plus the question doesn't ask anything about how many tosss there are.  Only about sum of 7 vs. sum of 8 which is specifically the last toss.

If you have any questions or more confusion, please ask.  If you feel it answers your accepting an answer or at least upvoting answers you like is considered the polite thing to do.

As stated, the dice rolling stops on the first sum of 7 or the first sum of 8.  I think it could be rephrased and maintain the same mathematical meaning as the following.   "Roll until the pair shows a sum of 7 or a sum of 8.  What is the probability you stopped on a 7, and did not stop on an 8?"  Remember,
This is a characteristic or very similar to "Negative Binomial Distributions", but negative binomial distributions also incorporate the total number of tosses.

Next, this pair of dice is cast until a seven appears twice or until each of a six and eight has appeared at least once. Show that the probability of the six and eight occurring before two sevens is 0.546. how would you go about this?

This is an apt problem for using odds  to get at the answer simply. (The term "odds" is unfortunately too often loosely used as synonymous with probability, which it is not !)
From your calculations,
odds in favor of getting $7$ before $8$ are $6:5$
hence the desired probability $ = \frac{6}{11}$
